Сумма трех первых и последних чисел
Я пытаюсь самостоятельно написать программу, которая разбивает шестизначное число на два трехзначных, затем складывает цифры в этих числах и сравнивает полученные суммы.
Однако, у меня получается бесконечный цикл.  Подскажите, что подправить, только пожалуйста, без значительных изменений.
int happyNum = 123402;
int sumOne = happyNum % 1000;
int sumTwo = happyNum / 1000;
int sum1 = 0;
int sum2 = 0;
while (happyNum != 0) {
    sum1 += sumOne % 10;
    sumOne /= 10;
    sum2 += sumTwo % 10;
    sumTwo /= 10;
}
if (sum1 == sum2) {
    System.out.println("Число " + happyNum + " является счастливым");
    System.out.println("Сумма цифр ABC = " + sum1 + " , а сумма DEF = " + sum2);
}


Вы не меняете happyNum в цикле, поэтому условие (happyNum != 0) всегда истинное и цикл бесконечный. Сделайте, например, 2 цикла, заменив в условии while happyNum в первом на sumOne, во втором на sumTwo. А лучше сделайте функцию, которая будет считать сумму цифр числа, переданного в нее

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Найти happyNumber. Код не работает. Java

@ПавелМиронов, вы получили ответ на этот вопрос почти два месяца назад.  Вы считаете суммы двух чисел -- вам понадобятся два цикла или два вызова функции.

@ПавелМиронов,  И две недели назад был аналогичный вопрос от вас: Поиск одинаковых цифр в сотнях, то есть, для нового ответа достаточно было взять int a = happyNum / 1000, b = happyNum % 1000;.

Условия изменились,теперь нужен один цикл

Кому нужен, ментору?

Да(И не вынося в отедльные методы ничего,ибо мы методы не изучали еще

Может плменять на другой цикл,напр. For?

@ПавелМиронов смотрите ответ, можно и с for, и с while.

Решение с циклом for и переменной p для степени 10:
int happyNum = 123402;
int a = happyNum / 1000, b = happyNum % 1000;
int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

for (int p = 1; p < 1000; p *= 10) {
    sum1 += a / p % 10;
    sum2 += b / p % 10;
}
if (sum1 == sum2) {
    System.out.println("Число " + happyNum + " является счастливым");
    System.out.println("Сумма цифр ABC = " + sum1 + " , а сумма DEF = " + sum2);
}

Решение с циклом while, без отдельной переменной p, в цикле будут изменяться старшие разряды a и младшие разряды b:
int happyNum = 123402;
int a = happyNum / 1000, b = happyNum % 1000;
int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

while (a != 0 || b != 0) {
    sum1 += a % 10;
    sum2 += b % 10;
    a /= 10;
    b /= 10;
}
if (sum1 == sum2) {
    System.out.println("Число " + happyNum + " является счастливым");
    System.out.println("Сумма цифр ABC = " + sum1 + " , а сумма DEF = " + sum2);
}


Спасибо........

@ПавелМиронов, зелёная галочка -- лучше, чем "спасибо"
